# DotNetOpenAuth NuGet Install - but Samples are problematic

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth, nuget-package, sample

I installed DotNetOpenAuth using NuGet and downloaded the 4.1 zipfile with samples, but am having difficulty trying to incorporate the Facebook.aspx sample into the new project. The sample code-behind refers to DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2, but I cannot seem to resolve this reference with the NuGet install. What am I missing?

**Note** that I built the DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock sample and added the refernce into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this NuGet command to install the [DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client package](http://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client/0.25.0-draft1):

```
PM> Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client -Pre
```